# Convert OpenGL 4-matrix into VRML T*R*S

Tags: opengl, 3d, linear-algebra, vrml, x3d

I am trying to export a scene from a direct-mode OpenGL program to VRML.

In both OpenGL and VRML, faces can be grouped into objects with their own translation, rotation and scale relative to the scene origin.

In OpenGL these are stored as a 4-matrix representing a translation and a rotation/scale in one matrix [[1]](http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_transform.html). In VRML these must be represented as separate translation, rotation and scaling vectors [[2]](http://graphcomp.com/info/specs/sgi/vrml/spec/part1/concepts.html#CoordinateSystems)[[3]](http://graphcomp.com/info/specs/sgi/vrml/spec/part1/nodesRef.html#Transform).

How can I decompose an arbitrary 4-matrix in this way?

I would prefer to use a library function to do this, to minimise the code I have to maintain and to reduce the chance of errors. I am using C# on Windows and can access any CLR or windows native DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [Matrix.Decompose code](https://github.com/mono/MonoGame/blob/develop/MonoGame.Framework/Matrix.cs#L2081) from the Monogame sources.

[Remember](http://www.mindcontrol.org/~hplus/graphics/matrix-layout.html) - OpenGL matrices are column-major and DirectX/XNA are row-major.

Hope that helps.

Comment: That has much of the required stuff, but falls short in a few places. Firstly, it uses Quaternions, whereas VRML requires axis-angle, and that library does not have a Quaternion -> AxisAngle function. I'm trying to add one now, but I was hoping for a library I could just drop in. Secondly, it decomposes M -> S*R*T (I think), whereas VRML wants M -> T*R*S. I can probably make this work by using multiple Translation nodes.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I decompose an arbitrary 4-matrix in this way?

The rightmost column of the transformation is the translation vector **T**.

The scale and rotation are a bit more intricate to extract. You need to find the rotation axis and rotation angle. Basically you're dealing with an eigenvector problem here: Find the vector that goes unchanged under transformation of the matrix. This is the case for the eigenvector. Rotations are orthogonal transformations. So any non-normal part of a rotation matrix is a scaling. You can extract this scaling by first *orthonormalizing* the matrix, yielding your the scaling factors **S**. Finally you can solve the eigenvector problem to find two antiparallel eigenvectors, being the rotation axis. The corresponding eigenvalue designates the cos(α) of the rotation, which gives you the rotation axis and angle **R**.

Comment: Eigenvector decomposition is not sufficient, since some of my matrices are both rotation and scaling combined. I asked for a library function, not a vague paragraph about linear maths.

Comment: @Rich: Yes it is sufficient, because you extracted the scaling beforehand by normlaizing the rotation matrix, which effectively spits out the scaling factors. As for a library. Ever linear math library will do those tricks. Like for example Eigen (Google it). If you want something smaller you can use my https://github.com/datenwolf/linmath.h which provides a function to convert a 4×4 rotation matrix into a quaternion. A normalized quarternion is effetively a rotation axis and a angle.

Answer (score 0):

SFMatrix4f/d and SFMatrix3/d have build in functions to decompose a matrix in its components. Here is the page from the specification: http://www.web3d.org/documents/specifications/19777-1/V3.0/Part1/functions.html#t-Matrix4Functions.

In JavaScript you can type:

```
function foo (matrix4f)
{
   var translation = new SFVec3f ();
   var rotation    = new SFRotation ();
   var scale       = new SFVec3f ();

   matrix4f .getTransform (translation, rotation, scale);
}
```

Some browsers support as fourth and fifth parameter to getTransform a scaleOrientation and center argument.